# Splash Screen in Android Studio with logo filling up?

Tags: android, splash-screen

Does anyone know any android studio tutorial to make a splash screen with an image or logo that fills in? As if it were a progress bar but an image.

I can't find anything.

Hope you can help me, thank you.

(Please tell me if you don't understand the idea I have)

EDIT:
I made a draw in paint to make it more clear.

imagine that the star is the logo that I want. The star would be filled with a color (in this case yellow) and once it had been filled in, it would enter the application, like a splash screen.

[image]

Comment: Your question is not clear, please consider adding an example image of what you want..

Comment: I added an image to make it clear, I've tried to find a video but can't find anything. Thank you for answer
@SoumikBhattacharjee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this library for your purpose.

https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/AndroidFillableLoaders

Sample Demo Video:

[image]

Sample Code

```
<com.github.jorgecastillo.FillableLoader
  android:id="@+id/fillableLoader"
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  app:fl_originalWidth="@integer/original_svg_width"
  app:fl_originalHeight="@integer/original_svg_height"
  app:fl_strokeColor="@color/stroke_color"
  app:fl_fillColor="@color/fill_color"
  app:fl_strokeWidth="@dimen/stroke_width"
  app:fl_strokeDrawingDuration="@integer/stroke_drawing_duration"
  app:fl_fillDuration="@integer/fill_duration"
  app:fl_clippingTransform="waves"
  app:fl_fillPercentage="@integer/fill_percentage"
  />
```